# how to correctly render a response on an gsp from on the same page as the request (REST call) in grails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails, groovy

I am new to grails and groovy.
I am trying to find out how to render a response from an action in a grails controller IN THE SAME gsp - but in a DIFFERENT SECTION OF THE gsp  - as the gsp that takes the request (in this case a web form gsp page)?

any links or turorials or just straight to the point "do this" kind of replies are welcomed.

```
========= background with my code attempt) =========
```

Here is the code I am working with. It is a Grails application in which I am using a bootstrap template (available for free on the internet of course).

Now the actual code itself for functionality works. What I am having an issue with is this:

I have a gsp page that uses a css template and another gsp temlate for layout (this is from the bootstrap theme). I can start the page with the gsp+css tempate using this code (snippet) in my gsp page:

```
<g:layoutBody/>
```

This allows me to call my calling controller code in this gsp file for the request:

```
<body>
<g:form name="form" controller="apiStart" id="form">
    <div><g:select name="protocolType" value="restCall" from="${["-select-", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]}"/> &nbsp <label>URL: </label><g:textField name="url" value="${url}" />
    &nbsp <label>username: </label><g:textField name="userName" value="${userName}" />  &nbsp <label>password: </label><g:textField name="passWord" value="${passWord}" /></div>

    %{--<div class="text-field"><label>URL: </label><g:textField name="url" value="${url}" /></div>--}%
    %{--<div class="text-field"><label>username: </label><g:textField name="userName" value="${userName}" /></div>
    <div class="text-field"><label>password: </label><g:textField name="passWord" value="${passWord}" /></div>--}%
    <br>
    <div><label>Use Advanced Parameters?</label><g:checkBox name="useAdvParms" value="${false}" /></div>
    <div class="text-field"><label>Header1: </label><g:textField name="header1" value="${header1}" /> &nbsp <label>Value1: </label><g:textField name="value1" value="${header2}" /></div>
    %{--<div class="text-field"><label>Value1: </label><g:textField name="value1" value="${header2}" /></div>--}%
    <div class="text-field"><label>Header2: </label><g:textField name="header2" value="${header3}" /> &nbsp <label>Value2: </label><g:textField name="value2" value="${header4}" /></div>
    %{--<div class="text-field"><label>Value2: </label><g:textField name="value2" value="${header4}" /></div>--}%
    <br>
    <div class="submit"><g:actionSubmit value="Submit" action="save"/></div>
</g:form>
</body>
```

And then this gsp code for the response:

```
<body>
<h3>API Test Results</h3>
API Tested: ${apiStart.url}, Response: ${apiStart.response3}
<br>
%{--<g:textArea name="myField" value="myValue" rows="20" cols="100"/>--}%
<div class="textarea"><label>Output</label><br><g:textArea name="myField" value="${apiStart.result3}"  />
</div>
%{--Responce Code: ${apiStart.response3}<br>--}%
%{--Response: <br> ${apiStart.result3} <br>--}%

</body>
```

My issueis this: ***it works fine as separate pages***. ***I want to render the results of the request on the same page as the calling request.***

in the screen shot attached: I want to put the results in the text box where it says "Output Displayed here...."
[image: screenshot of gsp page]

I assumed templates in grails is the way to go about it; but I get a Java Null pointer exception when I try to insert the template into that part of the code.

here is the template gsp code:

```
<div>
    API Tested: ${apiStart.url}, Response: ${apiStart.response3}
    <br>
    %{--<g:textArea name="myField" value="myValue" rows="20" cols="100"/>--}%
    <div class="textarea"><label>Output</label><br><g:textArea name="myField" value="${apiStart.result3}"  />
    </div>
    %{--Responce Code: ${apiStart.response3}<br>--}%
    %{--Response: <br> ${apiStart.result3} <br>--}%
</div>
```

======== UPDATE: Addidng controller code ===========
controller:

```
package hellograils

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;

import static javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseString;

class ApiStartController {

    def index() {

    }

    def save() {
        def apiStart = new ApiStart(params)
        apiStart.save()
        render (view: "apiStart", model: [apiStart: apiStart])

        System.out.println(apiStart.url);
        System.out.println(apiStart.passWord);
        System.out.println(apiStart.userName);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        System.out.println ("URI under Test is: " + String.valueOf(apiStart.url) + ". \n" + "Please stand by for results ... \n \n ");

        //String linkUT = apiStart.url;


//        apiStart.result3 = restTemplate.exchange(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class).getBody();
//        apiStart.response3 = restTemplate.exchange(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class).getStatusCode();



        if (apiStart.protocolType == "GET") {

            apiStart.result3 = restTemplate.exchange(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class).getBody();
            apiStart.response3 = restTemplate.exchange(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class).getStatusCode();
            render(view: "apiStart", model:[apiStart: apiStart])

            System.out.println(apiStart.protocolType);
            System.out.println(apiStart.result3);
            System.out.println(apiStart.response3);

        }

        else if (apiStart.protocolType == "POST") {

            //apiStart.result3 = restTemplate.exchange(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class).getBody();
            apiStart.result3 = restTemplate.execute(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class).getBody();
            apiStart.response3 = restTemplate.exchange(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.POST, null, Map.class).getStatusCode();
//            apiStart.result3 = restTemplate.exchange(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class).getBody();
//            apiStart.response3 = restTemplate.exchange(apiStart.url, HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class).getStatusCode();
            render(view: "apiStart", model:[apiStart: apiStart])

            System.out.println(apiStart.protocolType);
            System.out.println(apiStart.result3);
            System.out.println(apiStart.response3);

        }

        else if (apiStart.protocolType == "PUT") {

            render(view: "apiStart", "coming soon ....")

            System.out.println(apiStart.protocolType);
            System.out.println(apiStart.result3);
            System.out.println(apiStart.response3);

        }

        else if (apiStart.protocolType == "DELETE") {

            render(view: "apiStart", "coming soon ....")

            System.out.println(apiStart.protocolType);
            System.out.println(apiStart.result3);
            System.out.println(apiStart.response3);

        }

    }
}
```

=================== end of controller code ==================

and here is the domain controller code:

================ domain model code ==========================

domain:

```
package hellograils

class ApiStart {

    String url
    String userName
    String passWord
    String result3
    String response3
    String header1
    String header2
    String value1
    String value2
    String protocolType

//    static constraints = {
//    }
}
```

======================= end of domain ================

Can someone advise and show me the best way to do this?

thanks.

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the results pane in your gsp, but wrap it with a g:if tag. Supply a flag variable that determines whether grails renders that portion of the output or not.

```
<g:if test="${apiStart != null}"> 
  <div class="textarea">
    <label>Output</label><br>
    <g:textArea name="myField" value="${apiStart.result3}"  />
  </div>
</g:if>
```

In the edit method, define apiStart as:

```
def apiStart = params.apiStart
```

When the edit view is initially rendered, the results pane should not appear.

In the save method, do whatever you're doing, define the apiStart map, populate it, and redirect to the edit method passing the apiStart as a parameter.

```
redirect(view:'edit', params:[apiStart:apiStart])
```

Or something like that. Haven't seen your controller code...

Comment: Looks like your index method == my edit method.  Whatever method starts the workflow you are trying to accomplish. After a save, redirect to index, but pass in the results (apiStart) with the outcome populated.

Comment: that just made the page blank. Thare no posted results in the out put text area.

Comment: What does a debugging sessions tell you happens - a blank page generally means that something isn't quite right in the gsp code. I'd stick a render call in the index method, and make sure that I was passing the data I expected in the variables I expected to the view.

Comment: yes you are correct. let me clarify my comment. What I meant to say was: when I do as you mentioned above, I still get no output. In the console I can see the output (I am printing the output as I go along). The gsp renders a page successfully after I make the request. It's just that the output from the rest call is not displayed

Comment: I think I might not correctly understand what you posted as the solution. Can you walk me through this?

Comment: Maybe the gsp logic is simply <g:if test="${result3} != null">. In your form gsp, I don't see any references to" apiStartInstance.attribute" as might be typical for working on a Domain Class instance, just the attribute names themselves. (I'm not familiar with the bootstrap template you mentioned.

Comment: it worked ... partially!!! Using the example code you posted above, I get the output where I want it, but it replaces the panel above with the output as well (out put of the REST call). Any ideas???

Comment: I still not to get the exact rendering correct as this solution seems to be the closest to what I am targeting. I still need it to render to 100% of what I am Looking for